# Why are ball valves spherical instead of cylindrical?

Tags: valve

It seems strange to me that ball valves are ball-shaped, when I would have thought a rotating cylinder with a transverse hole cut in the same way would be easier and cheaper to machine. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This might be a question for the engineers that designed it, rather than a do-it-yourself home improvement community.

Comment: I'd venture a guess that it has more to do with economy of manufacturing as well as the total length of edges/perimeter that must be sealed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stopcocks use a cylindrical axle.

Ball valves use less metal and are more reliable because the seal is a simple circle, whereas in a stopcock an entire surface has to mate.

As far as machining is concerned, it is cheaper to make a ball than to make a cylinder of the same diameter and the same finish grade.

Comment: *" the seal is a simple circle, whereas in a stopcock an entire surface has to mate"* That's what I was looking for. Thank you. I am surprised that you say it's cheaper to machine a ball than a cylinder

Comment: @Borodin Why do you think ball bearings are much more common than roller bearings? It is because it is cheaper to make spheres than cylinders.

Comment: I'm not denying that it's true, it just seems very unintuitive

Answer (score 4):

A sphere allows for sealing with simple o-rings in a flat configuration. This simplifies design, component acquisition, assembly, and repair and maintenance.

Comment: I agree all the large ball valves I work on are ball's, Less material & easy to work on and replace seals. +

Comment: Please would you exaplin what you mean by *"in a flat configuration"*

Comment: Not bent. Not wrapped around a cylinder wall like a potato chip. See the orange seal in this image: http://www.globalspec.com/ImageRepository/LearnMore/20121/BallValvea9dd956faf7045eda3a8a92a5ba3352e.gif

Answer (score 0):

Not to be disagreeable, but the idea of calling a spherical valve a "ball valve" seems logical to me. To call a cylindrical valve a "ball" valve would be... more strange.

Actually, the term "ball valve" is distinguished as a kind of stopcock (that uses a sperical valve). But "stopcock" includes ball valves or the cylindrical kind of valve that you described. Stopcock is defined (by google) as: an externally operated valve regulating the flow of a liquid or gas through a pipe.

Cylindrical valves are the kind of valve that *most* faucets actually use (fancy cylinders are called cartidges or stem valves); but because ball valves are so popular (I guess), valves which are called "stopcocks" or "stop valves" tend to refer to the simplest cylindrical (or conical) valve; and less often does the term stopcock refer to a ball or stem valve. If you search for stopcocks online, you will probably find many cylindrical or conical valves which are used in chemistry apparatuses- especially because they are easier to disassemble and clean and they can be less prone to chemical and thermal damage.

But again, technically, a stopcock is a broader term which basically includes any valve, typically operated by hand.

Comment: @Tester101 _Q: Why are ball valves spherical instead of cylindrical?...strange that ball valves are ball-shaped... a rotating cylinder... would be easier and cheaper to machine... ideas?_ A: Cylinders are common. They are oft called stopcocks in chemistry and fancy ones are called cartidges or stem valves. Ball valve is a logical name for a spherical valve.

Comment: Note: In UK plumbing, a stopcock usually means the main valve supplying cold water at pressure into a house. The other valves in a house *typically* have different names according to purpose (service valve, isolation valve, check valve, float valve, pump valve) or construction (gate valve, ball valve).